# backendError accessing users.list in Admin SDK

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Our customers are getting errors trying to import users from their Google Apps domain into our application using users.list in the Directory API (Admin SDK). This was previously working, but for the past few days we've been seeing the following errors.

> OAuth users.list.execute error: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 OK { "code" : 503, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Service unavailable. Please try again", "reason" : "backendError" } ], "message" : "Service unavailable. Please try again" }

Does the Apps Marketplace app have to be enabled for the entire domain, or should this still work if it's enabled for a specific OU?

Comment: You are not the only one. We are experiencing similar issues since about 7 days and we are working with Google support to resolve this.

Comment: You may also find that the code still works with some domains but not all. Could you confirm this?

Comment: Yes it works with our own testing domains. It seems to be failing for large domains with more than >5k users.

Comment: Google is currently working to resolve this

Comment: The solution is to use the Customer property in your queries instead of the Domain property. You should set the Customer property to the value "my_customer". If for some reason you cannot do this, Google continues to work on the issue.

Comment: Our client got the same in group.members.list. Any ideas?