# Google Admin SDK Directory API - Service Unavailable Error while retrieving users

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

We have been using Admin SDK's Directory API to retrieve users from Google Apps Domain and sync it to our application. It has been working fine till now but since past 4-5days our client domain has been experiencing error while retrieving users.

```
Exception message : 503 OK
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Service unavailable. Please try again",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Service unavailable. Please try again"
}
```

I have referred to "[backendError accessing users.list in Admin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918224/backenderror-accessing-users-list-in-admin-sdk#)" . But Google hasn't replied yet. Can I know that when will this issue be solved or is there any solution present to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about it. Just wait and retry later.

Maybe you are interested in exponential backoff:

- https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/ExponentialBackoff
- https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors
- http://is.gd/OcGVUz